# eCognition TTA Mask : Aerial images in ecognition for supervised classification

Tags: digital-image-processing, ecognition, image-classification

I am using eCognition Developer Trial 8.0. I have rgb Drone Otho foto. We want to classify this image for various biotope types exist in that region. We have already an existing classification as a thematic layer that contains at least 100 of classes.

My primary idea was to classify based on TTA mask. So that I donot need to assign it by hand. I have genererated TTA mask using [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/252547/25989).

I do not have any idea if it is possible to classify the whole area/image based on TTA mask or how it works.
You can take a look of my data screenshots:
[image]

Comment: Yes, you can. When you load the TTA mask, classes will be added **Class hierarchy** with samples assigned by TTA mask. You can select them to perform a classification. Obviously, you need to perform a multi-resolution segmentation or another kind of segmentation first. Also, select object properties to extract response and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got the process diagram of doing image classification using TTA Mask in eCognition.

step 1: Multiresolution segmentation to generate objects

step 2: loading TTA mask for classification:

- **Classification**--> **Samples**--> **Load TTA Mask**
- You can control viewing TTA Mask or image layer using view settings.

step 3: create samples for NN Classification:

- **Classification**--> **Samples**--> **Create Samples from TTA Mask**

step 4: Select classes for NN: 
 - **Classification**--> **Nearest Neighbor**--> **Apply Standard NN to    Classes**--> all/some you want

step 5: process tree--> Classification-->level1--> filter(none)--> used class->all including unclassified

I hope it would also help others who have a similiar question.